# When using DocuSign Connect, is HMAC security only available for Aggregate delivery mode?

Tags: c#, docusignapi, docusignconnect

We want to setup DocuSign connect webhooks per envelope as we feel this will give us more visibility when the event was triggered. When reading the documentation it appears that HMAC security is only available when a custom configuration is set in the Admin panel or the API. If we set a custom configuration will the envelope level event settings take precedence and will HMAC work as expected?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. ***Thank you!***

Answer (score 0):

You can use HMAC signatures/verification for per-envelope webhooks. To do so:

1. Set up the HMAC secret(s) using the eSignature Settings app.
2. When you make the Envelopes:create API call, include the eventNotification object.
3. Within the eventNotification object, set the [includeHMAC](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/#schema__envelopedefinition_eventnotification_includehmac) attribute to `"true"` (it is a string attribute, not boolean).